# How to make a Android app's guide view animation like this?

Tags: android, animation

I want to set a guide view for my app like the gif show.!I use a scrollview to implement it ,but i cant listen the view's location to start my animation for it.some guys said ViewTreeObserver is ok to listen the view,but i dont know how to do it.Can you help me? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a Listview instead, you can use scroll listener the child views

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScollView>
  <LieanrLayout>
      ...
  </LieanrLayout>
</ScollView>
```